# Изменение содержимого ячейки в tablelayout android\eclipse

Tags: java, android

Я генерирую таблицу кодом. И после генерации мне нужно в определенной ячейке изменять содержимое. Как это сделать? Какая функция отвечает за это?

Comment: зависит от того, как вы генерируете таблицу кодом

Comment: Ячеек как таковых нету. TableLayout - это по факту LinearLayout с вложенными в него LinearLayout'ами. Ячеек нету, есть максимум строки, или столбцы

Answer (score 2):

```
View view = tableLayout.getChildAt(0);
if (view instanceof TableRow) {
    TableRow row = (TableRow) view;
    row.removeViewAt(0);
    TextView tv = new TextView(this);
    tv.setText("asdasasd");
    row.addView(tv, 0);
}
```

Comment: Вот так вот это можно сделать. Да, это рахитство, но оно работает.